# can I replace a String with a char in Java?

Tags: java, string, replace, char

I am working on a project where I take a user-inputted String and replace "and" with "&", "for" with '4', etc. and then prints out the modified String. How would I be able to do this?

PS: I know there's a replaceAll() function but that only works for characters, right? Is there any way I could use this in my code?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You don't need `replaceAll` (which takes a regex as input) - use [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: stringVar.replace("and", "&"); And so on

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to chang the string into chsr first then You can use the String's method called toCharArray() which converts the string into array of characters.

> String sWord hello;
>
> char[] cArray;
>
> cArray = sWord.toCharArray()

Then just use a combination of for loops and if-statements to replace the characters you need